# Rake db:create not doing anything (using mysql2 0..2.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, mysql2

I've been trying for a good while to get Rails to talk to MySQL. I was able to install the 'mysql2' gem (v0.2.7), create a new rails app defaulting to MySQL:

```
rails new mytest -d mysql
```

and `bundle install` everything.

However, when I run `rake db:create`, it simply hangs, no errors, no anything.
Running `rake db:create --trace` hangs at '** Execute db:create'.

My database.yml configuration:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: mytest_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: passwordforrootuser
  host: localhost
```

Using:

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- MySQL 5.5 Server (32-bit)
- Ruby 1.9.2

Really at my wit's end. Help???

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a try, if you include:

```
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

My setup, normally looks like:

```
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: foobar_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ***************
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Thanks, Christian. Had already tried it. Actually, switching the 'mysql2' gem's version from 0.2.7 down to 0.2.6 seems to have fixed it.